# Touchpad too sensitive

Tags: touchpad

I've got an low spec laptop and i installed ubuntu 15.04 on it. The problem is that the touchpad is too sensitive and even the smallest move of my finger moves the cursor. What can i do? I've tried a few methods but I'm not very familiar with linux commands.

Please help me!

Comment: Did you have a look at the pointer speed and acceleration in your System Settings under Mouse settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "synclient"? It comes with package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics, which probably is installed automatically. There's not much of a man page, unfortunately, so you need to google its options. I use it to configure my touchpad, but as I haven't needed to change gesture timings, I don't have those options, other than a vague memory that there are such options as well.